# Find an unbiased estimator from a random sample from the logistic distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, estimators, logistic-distribution

So I'm not sure where to start on this one, so any hints will help me because I'm a little lost on finding unbiased estimators.  So suppose $X_1, X_2,... X_n$ is a random sample from the logistic distribution with parameters a and B.  I want to find an unbiased estimator for $B^2$ but don't know exactly how or where to start. I know the cdf for the logistic distribution is $$F(x) = \left[1+\exp\left\{-\left(x-a\right)/B\right\}\right]^{-1}$$ but where do I go from here? Thanks so much.

Comment: Here's a hint. You can derive the variance of the logistic distribution using standard techniques. It is proportional to $B^2$... Unbiased estimation of the variance is a classical problem, from which you can immediately derive an unbiased estimator of $B^2$.

Comment: The variance is B^2*pi^2/3 so can I just multiply the unbiased estimator the sum of (x-x')^2/(n-1) by pi^2/3?

Comment: Correct, but double check the multiplier on the sample variance. If this is for homework, you may need to say why this logic is valid.